# Navigation links disappearing

Tags: branding

I have been having issues today with my top level navigation links disappearing when I go to the navigation link. It is only disappearing in the navigation window that allows you to edit the navigation, not along the header of the site. 
I have special permissions on individual links and as of right now everyone within our corporation can see the links regardless of what the permissions are set at.
Strangely, I can go to the edit navigation page and all the links be there one min and they are not there the next, "see image." This was working fine last week and I have never had an issue with it before. 
It's almost like the automatic sorting is kicking in and out when I have it set to manual.[image]
Does anyone have a clue what could be happening here?

Comment: have you tried looking in the log files?

Comment: This is very strange. The issue occurred several times over the weekend and Monday. I did look at the log file but I had other issues going on with the timer service not recycling so I was dealing with that as well. However, now that I go back to this issue, I can not seem to recreate it. Could it have been the timer service?